# Using Custom MembershipProvider without a Login control in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, authentication

We have got a custom `MembershipProvider` in `ASP.NET`. Now there are 2 possible scenario the user can be validated:

1. User login via `login.aspx` page by entering his username/password. I have used **Login control** and linked it with the `MyMembershipProvider`. This is working perfectly fine.
2. An authentication token is passed via some URL in query string form a different web sites. For this I have one overload in `MembershipProvider.Validate(string authenticationToken)`, which is actually validating the user. In this case we cannot use the **Login control**. Now how can I use the same `MembershipProvider` to validate the user without actually using the **Login control**? I tried to call `Validate` manually, but this is not signing the user in.

Here is the code snippet I am using

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["authenticationToken"])) {
    string ticket = Request.QueryString["authenticationToken"];
    MyMembershipProvider provider = Membership.Provider as MyMembershipProvider;
    if (provider != null) {
        if (provider.ValidateUser(ticket))
            // Login Success
        else
            // Login Fail
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After validation is successful, you need to sign in the user, by calling FormsAuthentication.Authenticate: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.authenticate.aspx

EDIT: It is FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx

Also, to redirect the user back where he wanted to go, call: FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.redirectfromloginpage.aspx

[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.authenticate.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You can set your own `FormsAuthenticationTicket` if the validation is successful.

Something like this;

```
if (provider != null) {
    if (provider.ValidateUser(ticket)) {
        // Login Success
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1, //version
            someUserName, //name
            DateTime.Now, //issue date
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(lengthOfSession), //expiration
            false, // persistence of login
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
        );

        //encrypt the ticket
        string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        Response.Redirect(url where you want the user to land);
    } else {
        // Login Fail  
    }   
}
```

Comment: I have been trying to know how the authentication actually worked. Thank you. It has helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

You are right in the case of storing the auth information as a cookie directly. But using a strong hash function (e.g. MD5 + SHA1) is great and secure.
By the way, if you use sessions (which is also just a hash cookie) you could attach auth information to it.